# 2 Windows licenses on 2 SSDs and switching them

Tags: windows, license, dualboot, licensing

I have an HP ZBook Fury G8 and It has a locked BIOS and very strict security rules in Windows.

I want to install and use my own Windows operating system, which will be on a different SSD. I plan to switch SSDs when I am at home and at work.

I tried this with Linux, and it worked perfectly. So, my questions are:

1. Is there any chance that my company will find out I am doing this? In computer will be only one SSD with system without additional storage.
2. How will the licensing work here? When I boot Windows after a fresh reinstall, the license usually renews based on the PC configuration and product numbers. How that works for 2 windows on the same machine? Perhaps use different windows 10 and 11? Is ths even doable?

Comment: Is there any chance that my company will find out I am doing this?   .... Yes.  This is a company question and is out of scope here.

Comment: If the company uses [Intel AMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology) then it is possible that they can monitor and access the PC regardless of what operating system is installed.

Answer (score 4):

The laptop was most likely bought from OEM with Windows already
installed. That means that the Windows serial is found inside the
BIOS/UEFI, and it will be picked-up automatically and used for
activation by the same Windows version, if installed on the second disk.

This means you'll be using the company's Windows license for your private
use, which the company won't like if it finds this out.

This setup will most likely work, but you'll be opening and closing
the laptop twice daily, and also unplugging and re-plugging the disks.
This will cause inevitable wear damage, and if the internal SATA plug
will happen to break, you will have a very awkward moment explaining
to your IT people what you were doing inside the computer.

I would advise to buy yourself a computer for your private use.